# Examples of set theory problems which are solved using methods outside of logic

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, examples

The question is essentially the one in the title.

**Question.** What are some examples of (major) problems in set theory which are solved using techniques outside of mathematical logic?

Comment: not sure whether any (major) problems have been solved in this way, but [algebraic set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+set+theory) might qualify as a technique.

Comment: Getting tenure? :)

Comment: Can you give an example problem for which this could conceivably happen?  I have a feeling that if someone asks, for example, a consistency question about Banach spaces, and then it turns out to have a ZFC answer via methods internal to functional analysis, then we would just say it wasn't a set-theoretical problem after all.

Comment: There are theorems in what is commonly referred to as "combinatorial set theory" or "infinitary combinatorics," such as Ramsey theory on infinite sets, that are proved using what one might call "combinatorial" arguments rather than "techniques of mathematical logic." For example there's the Erdos-Rado theorem http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1956-62-05/S0002-9904-1956-10036-0/ I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for, though.

Comment: There are some equivalences of CH in Analysis (like the existence of a Peano curve $(x(t),y(t))$ such for each $t$ one of the coordinate functions $x$ or $y$ is differentiable at $t$). This a theorem of Morayne.  The problems about near coherence of ultrafilters can be reformulated in the language of composants of $\beta \mathbb R_+$ (this is also a language outside of Set Theory).

Comment: More of a speculation than an answer: It's conjectured that every Suslin ccc forcing adds a Cohen real or a random real. Shelah showed that if such a forcing adds an unbounded real then it adds a Cohen real. Farah and Zapletal showed that if $\mathbb P$ is Suslin ccc and $\omega^{\omega}$-bounding then $RO(\mathbb P)$ is a Maharam algebra. Therefore, the above problem reduces to the following: Does every Maharam algebra adds a random real? Talagrand showed that there is a Maharam algebra which is not a measure algebra, solving an old problem by Von Neumann...

Comment: (cont) I'm not familiar with the details of Talagrand's proof, but it seems that his proof is purely measure theoretic. It is conceivable that a better understanding of Talagrand's ideas will lead to a solution of the above forcing theoretic problem (e.g. by showing that his algebra doesn't add random reals).

Comment: Does Cantor's diagonal proof that the reals are uncountable count as "outside logic"?

Comment: I don't think logic or set theory have such sharp boundaries that it is possible to provide a definitive answer. Huge parts of set theory, such as Borel equivalence relation theory or set-theoretic topology, are deeply connected with other related areas, and it could sometimes be difficult to describe a method as existing in only set theory or the companion area.

Comment: If you had asked for logic problems outside of logic, rather than set theory problems outside of set theory, then maybe [Tarski's problems about the first order of free groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Tarski's_problems) theory fit the bill, having been solved by methods of geometric group theory.

Comment: I found the paper [Dimension theory and forcing](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/zapletal/files/fremlin2.pdf) by Zapletal interesting. As it is stated in the paper, the solution is somewhat unusual in that the forcing is concisely defined and
analysed in terms of infinite-dimensional topology; however, its combinatorial
description is not readily available.

Comment: I agree with @JoelDavidHamkins that the boundaries are not clear. Does computability theory count as "logic"? If not, there are problems in intuitionistic set theory that are solved using computability theory.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, Could you give some examples or references for such problems?

Comment: there are applications of ergodic theory both to discrepetive set theory and to additive combinatorics, though I guess these are not in the scope of the intended question.

Comment: Possibly [my two comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131738/cluster-point-of-a-function-at-a-point/132607#comment308902_132607) might be an example. Also, Frederick Bagemihl and some of his students have obtained results linking the continuum hypothesis to [ambiguous points of planar functions](https://www.google.com/search?q="ambiguous+points"+"planar+functions"), especially Harvey Stanley Fox's 1972 Ph.D. dissertation [**The Continuum Hypothesis and Planar Functions**](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=41636) (not published).

Comment: I downvoted because answering this just leads to asking whether we call the methods "inside logic" or "outside logic", without any good way to draw the boundary.  But I don't mind distinguishing particular formulations as more set-theoretic or analytic or algebraic.  So I'd rather see, and I would upvote, an alternative question like:  "What set theory problems stated without much algebra have been solved using algebraic methods?"

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Joel David Hamkin's comment---Simon Thomas has provided applications of various super-ridigity theorems (from the ergodic theory of group actions) to the theory of the Borel complexity of countable equivalence relations, for example he shows that the universal countable equivalence relation is not essentially free

*Thomas, Simon*, [**Popa superrigidity and countable Borel equivalence relations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2007.08.003), Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 158, No. 3, 175-189 (2009). [ZBL1162.03029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1162.03029).

Answer (score 6):

I think the question could in principle have good answers (not turning too much on what is a method from logic) even though no one has found any yet.  As a counterfactual hypothetical example, Cantor invented the ordinal numbers motivated by considerations from Fourier analysis.  Maybe he also tried using Fourier analysis in his attempts to prove CH.  He didn't succeed, but imagine that he did.  Fourier analysis is classical mathematics from well outside of logic, so that would be a clearly satisfactory answer.  One can imagine more such examples, so the question is really: has anything like that ever actually worked?  Maybe not, but could it happen in principle?  I dunno.  I remember that it's possible to prove the Banach-Tarski paradox using the Hahn-Banach theorem (which is grounded in a weak form of AC), though that probably doesn't "count" since it doesn't actually recast BT as a functional analysis problem.

Dropping down from set theory, in computability theory, there's a famous and surprising theorem of Barrington that the complexity class NC1 can be solved by branching programs of fixed width 5, but not width 4 or less.  The reason 5 is the minimum is because S5 (the symmetric group on 5 letters) is not solvable but S4 and smaller are.  So that's group theory finding its way into a computability problem.  No reason such things can't happen in set theory.

(Too long for a comment, I guess).